# If antibiotics/paracetamol are relieving a patient's symptoms then can we establish that the root cause of symptoms is some sort of infection?

Tags: infection, pain, antibiotics, acetaminophen, pelvis-pelvic-bone

I don't think I can expand on the title without diving into my personal symptoms which I believe are against the rules of this stack-exchange. Nevertheless, even a general answer should be helpful right now.

Comment: Including the reddit post made your question off topic, so I fixed that for you. No one needs to know a thing about you to answer this question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Please clarify your question, since paracetamol is not an antibiotic. Are you asking if the patient's symptoms are relieved by paracetamol *and* antibiotics, or do you mean if patient's symptoms are relived by paracetamol *or* antibioitcs? Thank you.

If a patient's symptoms are relieved by paracetamol it does **not always** mean their symptoms are caused by an infection. Paracetamol is an antipyretic and analgesic, it reduces a patient's fever and provides pain relief.
However, not every source of fever and/or pain is caused by an infection. There are many non-infectious sources of fever. Most of them are immune-related diseases e.g. rheumatoid arthritis, lupus. Some are not, e.g. acute pancreatitis, cholecystitis, some neoplasias. But all are inflammatory *(usually)* .

As for antibiotics, if a patient's symptoms are relieved by antibiotics it is **highly likely** their symptoms were caused by an infectious disease. It's possible some antibiotics can be used to treat some non-infectious diseases. Personally I have never prescribed nor have I seen any medical professional prescribe antibiotics for this reason. But like many things, there are no absolutes.

I hope this answers your question, have a good day.

Comment: Apparently at least one antibiotic, azithromycin, does have noticeable anti-inflammatory properties as well.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azithromycin#Airway_diseases